# Infinitive absolute construction

Tags: absolute-construction

> After our third run Andrew shut down the engine, and we went our separate ways--he for a lunch break, I __ (explore) the city.
> Given answer: to explore.

This question means to test "absolute construction, but I was taught that infinitive absolute construction, i.e. I to explore, is very rare. So I want to know if this sentence is idiomatic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These "absolute" expressions are almost grammar free.

It works like this:

> Jack and Jill like different pets.  Jack, cats.  Jill, dogs.

The last two "sentences" aren't really sentences at all, just a couple of nouns.  You need to use the structure implied by the context to make any sense of this at all:  "Jack likes cats, whereas Jill likes dogs".

So "he for a lunch break"   means "He went (separately) for a lunch break".  But "I, to explore the town" means "I went (separately) to explore the town."
If you fill in the omitted verb, you can see it is just a normal catenative construction, with the infinitive giving the purpose.  There's no special "absolute infinitive" grammar here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what "infinitive absolute" means. I would call this "infinitive of purpose". It is common.

Some examples:

> I went out **to get some bread**.

> I climbed a ladder **to clean the windows**.

> He stopped me **to have a moan**.

> They campaigned for thirty years **to get the judgment overturned**.

Comment: I think "infinitive absolute" means that the infinitive isn't functioning as some element in the clause.  It's just there.